# Terminal-based (non GUI) virtual-computer program?

Tags: command-line, terminal, virtual-machine, virtualization

Are there any terminal-based (ie. non-GUI) virtual-computer programs out there?
I've been using programs like VirtualBox and QEMU, but they're obviously GUI-based...

I was hoping for a virtual PC program where I can do everything - create a new virtual machine, create it's disk, install OS (assuming a text-based installer is available) and start the VM on a terminal (thus replacing the host's shell with the VM's boot-message, log-in prompt and shell) - from a virtual-terminal/xterm-window/ssh/screen-session, instead of in a window under X.

The reason I ask, is that I often use ssh at work to connect to my home-computer, and the network is too slow for X or VNC.  Still I'd like to tinker with VMs...

Comment: jor1k ;) http://s-macke.github.io/jor1k/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `qemu`/`kvm`, you only get a GUI if you attach a video card to your VM and if you don't expose it as SPICE/VNC.

For instance, you can do (`zsh` syntax, with `grub2`):

```
grub-mkimage -O i386-pc -c =(print -l serial 'terminal_input serial' \
 'terminal_output serial' 
 ) -o grub.img configfile biosdisk part_msdos part_gpt ext2 \
   linux test serial halt minicmd cat
```

And start your VM with:

```
kvm -kernel grub.img -hda yourdisk.img -nographic
```

From the `grub` prompt, load the kernel from the disk passing `console=ttyS0`... option or equivalent on the system you're booting to have the console on serial. Remember to add a getty on the serial line as well.

Assuming you're running Linux in the VM, you can then update its grub config to display on serial and boot a kernel with serial console, and then you can boot your image disk directly without that grub.img.

To access the qemu "monitor", type <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> (where you can add/remove devices...).

You can have the `serial` port as a unix domain or TCP socket, instead of `stdio` if you like as well. Same for the qemu "monitor" interface.

Now, provided you have the `sgabios.bin` firmware, and that your VM doesn't use graphics (just VGA BIOS text output), you can also just use the `-curses` option:

```
kvm -hda yourdisk -curses
```

The VGA console is then shown in your terminal. If you need to access the qemu monitor, press <kbd>Alt-2</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox-es **can** be controlled from the terminal, via [VBoxManage](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html). The VirtualBox GUI is just an alternative, graphical client.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox works perfectly without the GUI. I have used it on the server side a lot. The VirtualBox GUI is just a well-decoupled convenience client tool. You can create and configure a VirtualBox machine using just console commands (almost as easily as with the GUI - there is nothing hard to learn/understand there, no new concepts and the command ([`VBoxManage`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html)) parameters reference and the examples are easy to google), attach an OS CD or a pre-built virtual hard drive image that would boot and start an SSH server then connect with SSH and do whatever you want.